Waterproof outdoor switch plate and blank cover for patio
I have electrical boxes on my patio which are planned to be used for patio lamp switches:

They are normal Carlon ENT boxes but because they were not high enough, the contractor used an extension ring.
Ideally I would install any switch (Decora style) I want (a “smart switch”). But even if not, it should just look nice (e.g., not huge surface mount boxes etc).
What is the right hardware I need to properly waterproof this as an outdoor switch?
Another box will not be used for a while and I’d like to just add a blank cover. Is this the right part? Will it be sufficiently water proof?

You'll need to clean the stucco off the face flange of the box extension.

Do you want "a huge surface mount box" and think those look nice (what this currently reads as) or is that something you don't want as you don't think it looks nice? It feels like a sentence with a "not" missing...

Good point, clarified. NO surface mount. As close to an indoor switch as possible, but of course, weather and water proof and code compliant. Also, I’ll clean the stucco from the flange

Not finding any outdoor smart switches that fit your bill, but dumb: https://www.amazon.com/Hubbell-Outdoor-Waterproof-Light-Switch/dp/B0849MZ51S
Comes with a foam gasket.

Good! (I may be able to "smartify" it with a small device in the box). It seems, there is no common way to use a conventional Decora switch outdoors -- is that right?

I mean the Hubbell switch seems pretty close enough to the Decora "paddle" style.  If you want to use a plain Decora outdoors, I think you're stuck using a weatherproof cover, which I think you said was not preferable.
